# Prove that $(\log(n))^{100} = O(n^{0.01})$

Tags: computational-complexity

I am really having difficulty getting started with this. Please help me prove that $$(\log(n))^{100} = O(n^{0.01})$$ (Should we use induction for this?)

Comment: Can you show $\log(n)=O(n^{0.0001})$ ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry

Comment: well, what do you know about logs and O(.)?

Comment: What is O(.)? I have seen that before

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that there is an $\bar n$ and a constant $M>0$ such that
$$
\left| {\log ^{100} \left( n \right)} \right| \leqslant Mn^{0.01}, \;\forall n > \overline n 
$$
Since it is
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\log ^{100} \left( n \right)}}
{{n^{0.01} }} = 0
$$
by definition of limit you can choose any $M>0$ and you have that there exists
$\bar n$ such that for every $n>\bar n$ it is 
$$
\frac{{\log ^{100} \left( n \right)}}
{{n^{0.01} }}
$$
and you have done.